# Hide/minimize mobile Safari toolbars when scrolling non-body element

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a website with a fixed position footer. Rather than deal with the nightmarish debugging that is fixed positioning on mobile, I had the brilliant epiphany to throw a flexbox together that fills 100% of the html/body height, with a fixed height footer, and the rest of the page is filled by a stretched main content element, that has `overflow-y: scroll`.

So there's no need for positioning the footer. It's simply pushed down to the bottom of the page by the content, and then the content element is scrolled, rather than the body.

Works great. But I just noticed when scrolling the content, the address and toolbar in iOS Safari never hide/minimize. I assume because the browser doesn't count overflow as an actual scroll.

No big deal... But, that's some good sreen realestate I'm losing...

So, is the toolbar hiding ONLY triggered when the main viewport is scolled? Or is there some crazy meta property or role attribute I can use to make the browser treat a different element as the main "frame"? I tried `minimal-ui` but that did nothing.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same one.

Comment: @Piotr Unfortunately not. With the increasing trend of progressive web apps, this seems (to me) to be a problem that should be getting worse, and gaining more attention. It should be expected that *sometimes* the main scrolling element won't be the body, and you'd expect there to be ways of dealing with that. But I still haven't found a solution